# Fetch database properties from spring cloud server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am able to fetch and store the mysql configuration properties from spring cloud server using @value but don't know how to use those values to connect to database.

server.properties

```
   spring-application-name=spring-cloud-config-server
   server.port=8888
   spring.profiles.active=native
   spring.cloud.config.server.svn.uri=url
```

project-master.properties

```
server.port=8081
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project_wdm
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Client-properties

```
spring.application.name = project-master
spring.cloud.config.uri = http://localhost:8888
```

Error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).`
```

Comment: Where the properties come from doesn't matter, Spring Boot will simply use them. Just use the default property names like `spring.datasource.url` and Spring Boot will create a datasource for it.

Comment: `***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
 If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
 If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).` this is the error

Comment: `spring.application.name = Project_Master
spring.cloud.config.uri = http://localhost:8888` this is the client properties file

Comment: `spring.application.name=config-server
server.port=8888
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project_wdm
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=********` this is the server properties file

Comment: Please don't add additinal information as comments, that is totally unreadable. Instead edit your question. The server properties are the properties for the config server, those aren't the properties that are served from it.

Comment: @M.Deinum now please check it

Comment: As stated in my last comment the properties in the server are for configuring the server. Those aren't the properties that are served from the config-server. Those should come from a git repo or local file resources.

Comment: svn-config is my repository of which i've given the link in server.propertie

Comment: The property file should be named `Project_Master.properties` instead of `svn-config.properties`. It will obtain properties based on the application name and active profiles. So currently it simply isn't loaded/detected. I would also suggest to remove or change the `server.port` as you are already running your config server on that port.

Comment: changed everything that you asked but still the problem persist

Comment: The client properties should be in `bootstrap.properties` and not in `application.properties`.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum i was also missing the client config jar in client

Answer (score 1):

Like @M.deinum said, if you also want to get the database related properties from the cloud config server, the config server details need to be in a file called `bootstrap.properties` and not `application.properties`. The reason for this is that this file is loaded earlier in the startup phase and when spring notices the `spring.cloud.config.*` props, it instantiates the client and gets the properties from the server before attempting to create the database connection.

Also, make sure to have the cloud config client dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

for debug, if you set the log level for `org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver` to debug, you will see in the log at startup entries of the type:

```
Found key 'some.prop' in PropertySource 'bootstrapProperties-app_name-app_profile' with value of type someType
```